# iScroll5 Infinite scrolling - lazy loading

Tags: lazy-loading, iscroll, android-lazyloading

A am developing a list based app, wherein I am tryin to use iScroll5 to implement lot of animations and smooth scrolling functions. I would like to do lazy loading of my contents wherein I want to load first 50 list elements to DOM and based on user scroll event asynchronously bind the next set of list elements to the DOM.

Am I on the right track to go with the iScroll5 -  Infinite scrolling API or is there any other library which does the job for me ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use infinite scrolling , means on page load some content are pre load and then user scroll down and other content are load on scroll with lazy loging, if i am understan right then please try to use jscroll jquery plugin.. it's very good for infinite scroll.
http://jscroll.com/   you can find here document and example of this plugin.

Regards,
vinit

Comment: Thanks Vinit, lemme have a look at it once

Comment: ok if you need to more guide line in jscroll then tell me i am here..have a good day